# Does a Jewish army require permission from Gedolim to wage war

Tags: army-military-war

Basically, as the title says, in the modern era without Sanhedrin, does a Jewish army require permission from the rabbonim of the times to wage war?
If they do, would the current conflict in Israel be considered a milchemes mitzvah and therefore not require approval?

Comment: I remember seeing that when there is no king then the leader gives permission, I have to check up the Rambam again

Comment: Consider Judges 20:23, 20:28 (among others)

Comment: Who would you consider "Rabbonim?" We have no Sanhedrin, so you'd ask random rabbonim and roshei yeshivos? Who gave them the authority to declare war?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a defensive war is labeled as a milchemes mitzvah and doesn't require consultation with the Sanhedrin you're good to go

Excerpted from Mishneh Torah hilchos melachim 5:1

> וְאֵי זוֹ הִיא מִלְחֶמֶת מִצְוָה זוֹ מִלְחֶמֶת שִׁבְעָה עֲמָמִים. וּמִלְחֶמֶת עֲמָלֵק. *וְעֶזְרַת יִשְׂרָאֵל מִיַּד צָר שֶׁבָּא עֲלֵיהֶם.*
>
> What is considered as milchemet mitzvah? The war against the seven nations who occupied Eretz Yisrael, the war against Amalek, *and a war fought to assist Israel from an enemy which attacks them.*